# Typescript Interface: Exactly one optional parameter is required

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I'd like to define an interface that allows you to supply `content` OR `content_object` but not both. You have to define one or the other. What is the simplest way to achieve this in TypeScript? I know I could say that content is `string | object`, but the rest of my code benefits if I can define it as described instead.

```
interface IModal {
    content?: string;
    content_object?: object;
}
```

Comment: Are you just wanting to know how to implement the constraints?

Comment: Yes. What I currently have says that both are optional, but both could be present as well. I want it to only allow 1, and ensure that exactly one are set.

Comment: You'll need some validation in your implementation class.  AFAIK you can't enforce such constraints in the interface itself.

Comment: You could also try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/typedcontract

Comment: Hmmm interesting package, but a bit overkill for this one scenario. Thanks though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
type IModal = { content: string; content_object?: undefined } |
              { content_object: object; content?: undefined }
```

This answer contains only code and is therefore bad according to automated systems.